# Is there some way to install a specific Python version when creating a virtual environment

Tags: python

I need to downgrade from python 3.8 to python 3.6 for Tensorflow in a virtual environment

I usually create environment with `python -m tempenv /path/to/venv`

I noted from this article that you can specify the interpreter when creating a virtual environment

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/installing-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-using-virtualenv/

But this requires downloading the interpreter separately

Is there a way to automatically do this in an elegant command or set of commands? So that it would download the needed version of Python (3.6) and the appropriate pip installation in the virtual environment folder?

Comment: I don't believe so. However, you could make it scriptable by using a package manager. Some examples:  `apt-get` for *nix systems, `chocolatey` for Windows, or `brew` for OSX

Comment: [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), you can have different isolated python interpreters for your venvs.

Comment: My $.02 is that you shouldn't do this.  The model put forth by the use of virtual environments is that you install all Python versions at the system level (not in a virtualenv) and then choose which version you want to use each time you create a virtual environment.  What happens the next time you want to use that version of Python?  Do you install it a second time in another virtual environment?  And then a third time after that?

Comment: I see the other comment here and @Grismar's answer.  I think they are both proposing the same idea...that you install the new Python version at the system level and the reference it in a new virtual environment.  Is there some reason you'd rather not do that?

Comment: @Steve Doesn't venv copy the Python executable anyway? It wouldn't be that much different no?

Comment: @flakes - I think you're right about the binary itself, but I don't think it copies all of the modules, either standard or added later with pip to the main versions.  I think that a virtualenv is much smaller than a full blown Python install - but I'm checking...maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Steve Oh interesting, I never considered that. I know that creating a venv doesn't allow access to system-installed packages (can only use the core modules). I just assumed it was a copy of those as well. Now I'm curious how that isolation is achieved.

Comment: @flakes - I did a test.  I created a new venv and checked its size.  it was about 15MB.  Then I checked the size of the install it was pointing to.  That size was about 205MB.  I also looked inside the venv's directory, and saw a bunch of symlinks to module files.  So it does appear that virtual environments make heavy use of sym links to avoid duplication.  This is on Mac and Linux.  I have no idea what happens on Windows.

Comment: @Steve Very interesting.. makes a lot of sense to do it that way. Today I learned.

Answer (score 3):

You can only create a virtual environment for the version of Python you're using to create it with.

Having said that, if you need virtual environments for different version of Python (e.g. 3.8.x and 2.7.x), you can simply install both version of Python and use the appropriate one to create new virtual environments with that version of Python in it.

As suggested by @flakes, you can also package managers to further automate the process and avoid having to manually pick and install versions of Python to use - to your preference. Tools like `pyenv` can then make your life easier switching between versions of Python. However, then we're getting into opinions on what's better or easier - you can make it work with stock Python as suggested.

Comment: Want to add in the comment I made about package managers? I think that somewhat answers the question of simplifying the setup.

Comment: @flakes - +1 to that.  I use Brew since I'm on a Mac.  And then I use the `pyenv` tool to manage the multiple versions.  `pyenv` works really well, at least for me.  But then again, if you use a virtualenv for every one of your projects, you may not need to do much with `pyenv`